# polkit tigervnc Unregistered Authentication Agent configuraiton

Tags: fedora

The system is Fedora 24. The error occurred as the result of an upgrade from fc23. The vncserver@:service package has been edited to reflect the user configuration. The command `systemctl restart vncserver@\:2.service` results in an error exit. `journalctl -xe` shows:

```
Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process
```

This appears to show up as a polkit configuration issue. Is this a polkit issue? Is there a polkit configuration document showing how to configure polkit to support vnc?

Comment: it does not look like that error what caused your `vnc` failed. Do you see any AVCs in `audit`?

Comment: No the only audit log message is: type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1480344359.964:1191): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=vncserver@:2 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'

Comment: That said, the messages log shows an error 'HOME environment variable not set'. Which process is creating that message? Is this a bash shell issue that is missing a variable setup? Is there an environment variable required in the VNC scripts?

Answer (score 2):

use the next config of service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=<USER>
PAMName=login
WorkingDirectory=/home/<USER>

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1600x900 -localhost no -fg -cleanstale -PlainUsers * :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

PAMName - is neccessary line to work properly with polkit!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Why though?